# Guava's EventBus component performance in Android app

Tags: android, guava

I am prototyping an application and I though I would try to use Guava's EventBus component to get rid of some code I was keeping writing again and again to propagate events from fragments to activities for instance.

To my surprise, I got a really big performance hit when activities are starting.

I only do a single EventBus.register call on the activity itself. Removing that call brings back the activity start time to usual. I also noticed quite a lot of garbage collection going on at that time.

Would anyone have advice about Guava's EventBus and Android? Should I simply go back to the simple fragment listener pattern? Any other library (I was about to try mbassador too, but I am running out of prototyping time).

Comment: Square's [Otto](http://square.github.com/otto/) is an EventBus fork optimized for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply not using any event bus implementation by lack of time (and the project is small, so it was more of a personal experimentation).

However, there are a number of alternatives to Guava's EventBus as said by L. Wasserman: [Square's Otto](https://github.com/square/otto), [mbassador](https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador), ...